# Grails eager fetch doesn't retrieve all data

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have the domain classes:

```
class Person {
    static hasMany = [ items: Item ]
    static fetchMode = [ items: 'eager'  ]
    String name
    Set items
}
class Item {
    static belongsTo = [ owner: Person ]
    String name
}
```

If I leave `static fetchMode = [ items: 'eager' ]` in place, then calling `getItems()` only returns about 10% of the items. If I remove the fetchMode, then `getItems()` returns all the items. Any idea why eager fetch results in retrieving less than all the stored data?

Comment: Please share the answer to your question as an _answer_ and then accept the answer, otherwise this question will continue to linger in our 'Unanswered Questions' list. If the question is no longer relevant, please flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

In February 2011, this had been identified as a [bug](http://www.blueleftistconstructor.com/2011/10/12/grails-broken-list-on-domain-object-fetchmode-eager-wait-no-join/) in Grails 1.04, according to [grails.org](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-995). As of July 2012, the bug is listed as closed, so the problem should be resolved.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139075/should-old-questions-with-a-solution-in-the-comments-but-no-posted-answer-be-ans) for why I'm answering an old post.